# I am importing a csv in pgadmin but I keep getting an error

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4, csv-import

I'm new to coding and I keep trying to import a csv file and getting an error(image provided below). I have tried importing it with a utf-8 encoding as others suggested, but that failed. Additionally, I tried using multiple copy statements to no avail.

[the image below is the error I am getting]

[image: 1]

Comment: you may need to trancant your table. (make a backup before you do this) or use a restore option for said table

Comment: 1) Do not use images for textual data, copy and paste the text as update to your question. 2) The image does not show the actual error. Look in the Postgres log for the complete error message and add to your question.

Comment: You now have an inline image instead of text. Please do as requested and copy the message as text and paste into your question.

Comment: Also there should be a block between `Stop Process` and `Failed` that shows the actual error.

Comment: You seem to be using a buggy version of pgAdmin which fails to relay error messages correctly.  You should upgrade.  Or just use the command line.